# JavaFX - MeshViews not visible on screen

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, javafx-3d

I am trying to add a group contains several MeshViews that were read from a file to the center of a borderlayout.  I am using a FXML file to define the layout.  I have given the center AnchorPane an fx:id "centerPane" and the group containing the MeshViews a fx:id "centerGroup".  I do not get any errors, but nothing appears on the screen in the center pane.  I was doing a similar thing when I first started where I manually created a meshview and it would appear in the center pane (but then I was using the setCenter method of the borderpane object (which I had also assigned an fx:id name to so I could access it from within the controller code.  I will include the fxml portion and lines from controller below that are directly involved.  If someone could help me figure out how to get the meshviews to appear I would really appreciate the help.  I've read most of a JavaFX book and for some reason still struggle with this.  Thanks.

From the FXML file:

```
<center>
  <VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0">
    <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="centerPane" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" 
           prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <children>
              <Group fx:id="centerGroup" />
        </children>
      </AnchorPane>
    </children>
  </VBox>
</center>
```

Lines from controller file:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane centerPane;

@FXML
private Group centerGroup;

(inside of a for loop I add the meshviews from an array list into the group)
for( - ; - ; - ){
  centerGroup.getChildren().add(meshViews[i]);
}

PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);

PointLight redLight = new PointLight();
redLight.setColor(Color.RED);

PointLight greenLight = new PointLight();
greenLight.setColor(Color.GREEN);

( I have tried all three below.  middle one gave duplicate child error. )
//borderPane.setCenter(centerGroup);
//centerPane.getChildren().addAll(centerGroup, redLight, greenLight);
centerPane.getChildren().addAll(redLight, greenLight);
```

I believe that is enough code to paint a picture of what I am trying to fix.  I will attach a picture of the gui to show that while the code runs and I am printout out to the console the number of meshviews read from the file and the number is correct, nothing appears on the screen.  Thanks for your help.

[image: Pic showing center of GUI still blank]

Comment: `BorderPane` has problems with children that are not added via `center`, `left`, `right`, `top` or `bottom` properties. It's hardly a appropriate layout for a 3d scene. Furthermore without knowlege about the `MeshView`s there's simply no way to tell if the meshes are culled or hidden by the near/far clip planes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the camera to the stage

```
yourStage.setCamera(camera);
```

add the camera in your group

```
centerPane.getChildren().add(camera);
```